# Resetting <select> value after updating <option> tags

Tags: jquery, select

I've pasted my code below. Basically, I want to update the options of a select box and reset it's value afterwards to the value it had prior to the options being updated. Unfortunately this is not working. Any idea why?

```
rebuildMeasurements = function(measurements, measurement_unit_id) {

    var selects = $('select.measure, select.yield_measurement_unit');
    var selected_value;


    $(selects).each(function() {

        $(this).data('selected_value', $(this).val());

        console.log('Original Value: ' + $(this).data('selected_value'));
        // this outputs what we would expect, the original value of the select box

        $(this).empty();

        $(this).append('<option value="_new">New Measurement...</option>');

        for(x in measurements) {
            $(this).append('<option value="' + measurements[x].measurement_unit_id + '">' + measurements[x].measurement + '</option>');
        }

        $(this).append('<option value="_new">New Measurement...</option>');

        $(this).val($(this).data('selected_value'));

        console.log($(this).val());
        // this does NOT output what we would expect, but instead outputs the value of
        // the first option in the select box, even though we explicitly set the
        // value to the original value directly above this line.

    });

    $(current_measurement_select).val(measurement_unit_id);

};
```

## Answered

This is terribly embarrassing, but it turns out I was using a different value parameter when adding the new option tags than I was in the original HTML, which is why the values did not match up. Many of these code variants work when I fixed that problem. Thanks so much for the help everybody :).

Comment: Why do you have an `each` function, are there several selects?

Comment: Is the page being reloaded at some point? It would be helpful if you gave a full working example of the issue.

Comment: @morgar Yes, there are multiple selects that I'm updating the options for.

Comment: @patrick dw no, the page is not reloaded.

Comment: @Shawn: What is triggering the code? Your code works fine for me. The value is successfully retained and reset on the new option.

Comment: @laurence burke I'm storing the currently selected value in the data property of the object. See the 2nd line of code.

Comment: @patrick dw Let me update the post so you see the entire function. The function is called after an AJAX request for some JSON data is called.

Comment: When you do `$(this).val($(this).data('selected_value'));`, does `$(this).data('selected_value')` have the expected value?

Comment: @all if he empties `$(this)` doesn't that empty `$(this).data` since its a property of `$(this)`

Comment: @Shawn: And you're certain that the old value is an exact match to the new one in the JSON data?

Comment: @Laurence: No. The [`empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) method just clears descendant elements. It has no direct effect on the element against which it is called.

Comment: @morgar Yes, it sure does. If I console.log it directly before that command it's set properly.

Comment: @Shawn Berg http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/#comment-112420971 says when you go in and out of context with data it seems to loose its "data".

Comment: @Shawn: Please update your question with a sample of the JSON data you're working with.

Comment: @Laurence: Read the comment below that one. OP here is not using `$.data()` (as is the one with the context issue). He's using `$(element).data()`.

Comment: I figured out the problem and described the issue in the OP. Thanks for your help everyone. You'd think it was Monday for me :(. Sorry about that!

Comment: @Shawn: Not a problem, but go ahead and post your solution as an answer so you can "Accept" it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(this).find('option[value=' + $(this).data('selected_value') + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it, but I think its an forloop error:

```
 for(x in measurements) {
                $(this).append('<option value="' + measurements[x].measurement_unit_id + '">' + measurements[x].measurement + '</option>');
            }



  x here is an item in measurements, so you must change it from  :
```

`measurements[x].measurement_unit_id`

to
 `x.measurement_unit_id`,

may be this will help you

Comment: Because there are several `<option>` elements being created, it is likely that OP is dealing with an Array or Object of objects, something like this: `measurements={1:{measurement_unit_id:'value',measurement:'value'}, 2:{measurement_unit_id:'value',measurement:'value'},etc...}`

Answer (score 0):

You have two options with the value `_new`, which might cause problems for that specific option, but other than that there is no problem with the code.

I tried it out in jsfiddler here: http://jsfiddle.net/CXrqp/

I added a prefix parameter to the function so that I can see the change, but other than that it's the same code.

Check if you see any difference in the usage of the code.